# Preconfigured Ubuntu install iso / Custom installation routine

Tags: installation, iso

Is it possible to take the Ubuntu server iso and modify, so that you can create a custom installation routine?

The idea behind this is, that I'm going to deploy Ubuntu on a number of similiar PCs at work. They all need the same configuration, except for some variables, like network interfaces, etc. I don't really want to run the setup on 50+ PCs and then afterwards run around and make all changes over and over again.

So, is it possible to alter the installation routine of the Ubuntu iso? Thing I would like to be able to do:

- Add new input fields, like "IP address"
- Add/Remove default packages
- change config files